# how do I install a software I've prebuilt with `make`?

Tags: make, docker

*short version*: make install tries to recompile the project. I just want to place all the files in the right places.

*long version*:
I've created a docker container for building the projects that I want. It was a success. The rationale is that I don't want to install all the dev dependencies like pcre-devel and such on my final docker container, say, just for the sake of building ag (the silver searcher).

So the process is: I pre bake my sources with ./configure and make. then I go to my final container and only run make install. As I understand, make install just copies files to the right places. But it is instead, trying to recompile the project. I have already issue make, so why make install is trying to rebuild the projetct again?

The specific project that is doing that is ag, [the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)

I get this error:

```
bash-4.2# ./ag --version
ag version 0.32.0

Features:
  +jit +lzma -zlib
bash-4.2# make install
(CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh             /opt/sources/the_silver_searcher/missing autoheader)
rm -f src/stamp-h1
touch src/config.h.in
cd . && /bin/sh ./config.status src/config.h
config.status: creating src/config.h
config.status: src/config.h is unchanged
  CC       src/ignore.o
In file included from src/ignore.c:10:0:
src/options.h:7:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcre.h>
              ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/ignore.o] Error 1
bash-4.2#
```

of course i do not want to install the pcre-dependency. but that should not be a problem because I have the binary already in place. What is happening?

Comment: you need the pcre headers. They should be in a package called `libprce-dev` or `libpcre-devel` or something like that.

Comment: There are several ways this could have gotten confused.  Unfortunately, your information is not sufficient to tell what.  When you copied the files over did you copy everything in a way that preserved the timestamps?  If the timestamps from the original build directory weren't preserved in the copy, it may think the binary is older, so it needs to be rebuilt.  Also if some of the intermediate files are missing, make can decide they need to be rebuilt.  But an answer on a different approach is in the works...

Comment: use `checkinstall` to build a **package** in your dev container for installation on the target container.  Or just use the packages pre-built for various distros and *bsd that are recommended in the silver-searcher README.md on github.

Comment: @MAP, I've copied the dependecies over my docker container with the Dockerfile `ADD` instruction. How can some intermediate files be missing with that approach? Do you think there could be extra file produced that live outside the silver_searcher repo folder?

Comment: @cas I use a centos container and the yum repo has no rpm for the_silver_searcher whatsoever. So my options are building it from source or creating an rpm. Now, in the case of the silver searcher, wouldn't it be sufficient to just copy the ag binary to /usr/local/bin?

Comment: That would be the bare minimum to get the job done in as quick and dirty a fashion as possible.  If you care at all about long term maintenance of the system, or if you want the man page too, build a package.  I really don't get why so many programmers are scared of packages and packaging tools. it's not hard, packaging is a useful skill to have, and it can save you a huge amount of hassle in future at the price of a small effort now.  The github repo even includes a `the_silver_searcher.spec.in` file so the effort in this case is tiny.

Comment: You're right cas. Creating a RPM for my distro is a useful skill to have and i should master it.

Answer (score 0):

For some projects the "install" phase can be fairly simple.  So a different approach might be to run `make -n install` on the machine where you compiled everything.  This will evaluate what's needed for an install and print out *but not execute* the commands.  If this turns out to be relatively short, you can just cut-and-paste between two terminal windows to execute them manually on the target.  There may even be a target in the Makefile that packages it up for you (although you may want to take a look at the Makefile.in which may be easier to understand).